# How can I split string that have "[*word*]" as its part

Tags: c#, string

Example:
For string like this one: "**www.google.com [Google]**" split parts would be:
1. "**www.google.com**"
2. "**Google**"

Same split result for "**www.google.com[Google]**" (no space between two parts in this case)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps with `String.Split`:

```
string[] parts = input.Split('[').Select(s => s.Trim('[',']', ' ')).ToArray();
```

If such a string is possible and should also yield only two parts:

```
www.google.com    [[[Google]]]
```

You can use `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`:

```
string[] parts = input.Split(new []{'['}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(s => s.Trim(']', ' ')).ToArray();
```

Comment: Wouldn't this also split "**www.google.com [Google[**" into "**www.google.com**" and "**Google**"? I'm not sure that's exactly what the asker wants.

Comment: @hypehuman: depends on how strict the format is and how he wants to handle invalid input if it's possible. If it's not possible at all simple string methods are sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex:

```
([\w.\/]*)\s*\[(\w*)\]
```

You will have two groups you can then extract from the match:

```
1.  [0-14]  `www.google.com`
2.  [16-22] `Google`
```

Online demo: https://regex101.com/r/vX8hS7

Example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/IPDuPo

```
string input = "www.google.com[Google]";
Match match = Regex.Match(input, @"([\w.\/]*)\s*\[(\w*)\]");

foreach(Group group in match.Groups)
{
    Console.WriteLine(group.Value);
}
```

Will output:

```
www.google.com[Google]
www.google.com
Google
```

Note that on the online regex demo the entire match is not included as group, but in .NET the entire match is included as the first group as shown in the output.

Comment: Watch out with the \w metacharacter: it won't match a forward slash, so if the string started with "http://", it would not capture that part of it.

Comment: Also it looks like your dotnetfiddle link is using a different regex.

Comment: @hypehuman good catch! updated the discrepancies and added the forward slash